# Is it okay to say "She is in a red bracelet, a silver necklace, sun glasses and golden earrings" and "to put the key in the keychain"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, word-request, phrase-request

We often say "**She's in a baseball cap and red shoes**".

Similarly, can we say "**She is in a red bracelet, a silver necklace, sun glasses and golden earrings**"?

This is a picture of a keychain and a key

[image]

Do we say "**to put the key in or on the keychain**" and "**to put the keychain in or on the key**"?

Comment: I think you wear jewellery and you can be in clothes. You put a key on the keychain.

Comment: The thing in the picture is a key on a key ring. There's no chain there.

Comment: No, Tom, she is wearing those things. You cannot be "in jewelry" in English.

Answer (score 1):

She's in (or she's wearing) clothes (including shoes and hats ... and sunglasses!) but she's wearing jewellery (not 'she's in' a necklace, bracelet or nose piercing).

'To put a dog on a chain' and 'to put a chain on a dog' are equivalent. The same applies to key chains (or key rings) and keys.

'To put something *in* a chain' is usually to make something figuratively or literally a link in a chain (and not to add something to the end of the chain).

To put lots of things in a chain is to make a chain in which each of your things forms a link. "He put the daisies in a chain to make a floral crown."

Answer (score 0):

“She is in a baseball cap and red shoes” could be interpreted as” ... and nothing else”. Use “she wears a baseball cap and red shoes”.

You put a key on a keychain or a key ring. Usually you have more than one key on a key ring.

Comment: We use _in_ of clothes, but not jewellery or accessories such as sunglasses.